# В чем разница между max-width и min-width?

Tags: css

И обязательно ли при адаптивной верстке указывать screen

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/максимум

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/минимум

Answer (score 4):

Капитан Очевидность здесь!

max-width это максимальная *(верхний предел)* ширина;

min-width это минимальная *(нижний предел)* ширина;

Если речь идёт о адаптивной вёрстке CSS, эти параметры используется в условиях **CSS media queries**. Пример: тут стили будут применяться если ширина экрана не больше 600 пикселей

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* CSS-стили */; }
```

А вот здесь если ширина экрана меньше 600 пикселей, свойства НЕ будут применяться. А если шире - то будут..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { /* CSS-стили */; }
```

Такие дела.

Comment: _А вот здесь наоборот, если экран шире 600 пикселей, свойства НЕ будут применяться._ - наоборот же будут, тут же стоит `min-width`

Comment: @Grundy верно, исправил ответ. Торопился когда писал)))) Спасибо

Comment: Не только в условия, к "обычным" стилям их тоже можно применить.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 совершенно верно